# Unable to show spinning icon when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

The below code gets the data from back end and displays it on the browser on page load. When user clicks on Reload data button , again it has to get the data from backend and display on the browser. The issue is that when user clicks on Reload data button, I need to show the spinning icon and once the data is loaded it will be replaced with the data. With the below code spinning icon is showing but somewhere down the page, it is still occupying the space of $scope.html with the old data but showing blank and after the blank space it is displaying spinner.How can I show the spinner as soon as user hits the Reload data button?

```
<table style="width:100%;height:80%;" ng-controller="loadingSampleCtrl">
<tr> <td><button type="button" ng-click="loadData()">Reload data</button></td></tr>
<tr ng-show="loading"> <td colspan="5" style="white-space: nowrap;text-align: center; font-size:36px;"><div class="loader"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ></i> Loading<span class="loader__dot">.</span><span class="loader__dot">.</span><span class="loader__dot">.</span></div></td></tr>
         <object-reloadable></object-reloadable>
 </table>
```

js code:

```
app.directive('objectReloadable', function() {
var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
var currentElement = element;

scope.$watch('pdfName', function(newValue, oldValue) {
 if (newValue !== oldValue) {
     scope.loading = false;
     scope.pdfName = newValue;
      if(scope.pdfName.filePath == "undefined" ||  scope.pdfName.filePath==null){
scope.loading=true;
} else {
alert("in else");
scope.html = '<object style="width: 100%; height: 1200px;overflow-y: hidden; cursor:pointer;" type="application/pdf" data="' + scope.pdfName.filePath + '" ></object>';
/* scope.pdfName = newValue;*/
scope.loading=false;

}var replacementElement = angular.element(scope.html);
    currentElement.replaceWith(replacementElement);
    currentElement = replacementElement;
}
});
};
return {
restrict: 'E',
scope: false,
link: link
};
})

myApp.controller('loadingSampleCtrl', function ($scope, FilesService) {
$scope.loadData = function () {
$scope.loading = true;
$scope.html='';
FilesService.fileRead().then(
function (response) {
     $scope.filePathAndName = response;
       if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
    $scope.IEBrowser = true;
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.pdfName = response;
       }, 0);
    } else {
    $scope.IEBrowser = false;
    $scope.filePathAndName = response;
     $scope.loading = false;
     }
},
function (errResponse) {
    $rootScope.showError("Internal error" + errResponse);
});

}
$scope.loadData();
});
//service call
_myFileServiceFactory.fileRead= function(){
var deferred = $q.defer();
var repUrl = appURL+'/myFilesData/generateDefectsSummaryPDF.form';
$http.get(repUrl).then(
    function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
    },
    function(errResponse){
        console.error('Error ' + errResponse);
        deferred.reject(errResponse);
    }
);
return deferred.promise;
}
```

PS: I have assigned `scope.html=''` wherever required but still when user clicks on Reload button it is still showing blank space and then down somewhere showing the spinning icon.

Comment: can u provide in fiddle?

Comment: It has lot of dependencies,,i have provided the complete code in my post..